# Can client.available (TCPClient) be delayed?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using TCPClient to read data form an XML Interface of a machine.

To get the full XML response, I use:

```
        byte[] data = new Byte[1024 * 1024];

        int l = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        int pos = l;

        while (client.Available > 0)
        {
            l = stream.Read(data, pos, client.Available);
            pos += l;
        }
```

Sometimes it fails to read the full file. When I stop with the debugger, 'client.available' contains a value >0 !

I am very confused. How can this be?

Is there a way around this?

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Is it possible it reads in what data there is in your first read, empties the buffer (so Available == 0) then skips your while loop? And then data comes in so Available > 0.

Comment: TCP data is broken down to max datagram of 1500 bytes and can be slit by routes and servers into smaller pieces..  So yes the data can be delayed.  You have to either put a byte count at beginning of data or add a character at the end of the data (not contained in the file) to make sure you get the entire data before processing.